# Selecting values in Pivot Table

Tags: vba, pivot-table

when I try to run this easy macro

```
Sub Test0()
 Workbooks.Open Filename:="my_file.xlsm"
 Windows("my_file.xlsm").Activate
 Sheets("pivot").Select
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("List").CurrentPage = _
  "Bla"
End Sub
```

I obtain Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument.
On other documents this code worked fine.
Could you please help?

Comment: are you sure you have items in all `PivotTables` with "Bla" ?

Comment: No! You are right, just changing Bla to bla made it working perfectly. Silly me. Thanks a lot.